# How to Solve the nonlinear first ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to Solve the nonlinear first ODE ?

$y' = (y-1)^2 (t^4 e^y +\sin(y^2))$ , with $y(0) =1$

What I know only is How to solve the linear first ODE , I don't know about the nonlinear at all .

Comment: Are you supposed to numerically approximate it?  Because that looks impossibly difficult unless there's a trick I'm not spotting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, this is a trick.  See, the problem looks impossibly hard, but if you plug in the initial condition, you get $y' = 0$, so $y$ never changes!

Comment: Wow, you saved me !

Comment: When a problem looks too bad to be true, it sometimes is!

Comment: $y=1$ is the only solution